# Improve performance of this python function

Tags: python, performance, numpy

```
def _partition_by_context(self, labels, contexts):
    # partition the labels by context
    assert len(labels) == len(contexts)
    by_context = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        by_context[contexts[i]].append(label)

    # now remove any that don't have enough samples
    keys_to_remove = []
    for key, value in by_context.iteritems():
        if len(value) < self._min_samples_context:
            keys_to_remove.append(key)
    for key in keys_to_remove:
        del by_context[key]

    return by_context
```

1. labels is a numpy array of floats.
2. contexts is a python list of tuples.  each tuple is of form `(unicode, int)`: example `(u'ffcd6881167b47d492adf3f542af94c6', 2)`.  context values are often repeated.  For example there may be 10000 values in the contexts list, but only 100 distinct values.
3. `len(labels) == len(contexts)` is true, as asserted in first line
4. label at index i is associated with context at index i.  that is, `labels[i]` and `contexts[i]` "go together"

Point of this function is to partition the values in the labels by context value.  Then at the end, remove dictionary entries if the label count is too low.

So if all context values were the same, return value would be a dictionary with a single entry, key=context, value=list of all labels.

If there were N distinct context values, return value would have N keys (one for each context) and value of each would be a list of labels associated with a particular context.  Ordering of labels in the list is not important.

This function is called millions of times with different args.  I've determined it's the bottleneck using [gprof2dot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gprof2dot).  Much of the cost is in the list append() calls in the first for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Since you're only interested in the number of labels, try using a defaultdict with int instead of list, and just increment instead of append.

Comment: @jpkotta: I'm not only interested in the number of labels per context.  I need all labels per context, so I can compute stuff like mean and stdev of the labels per context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        by_context[contexts[i]].append(label)
```

with

```
for context, label in zip(contexts, labels):
    by_context[context].append(label)
```

and instead of using `keys_to_remove`, try

```
n = self._min_samples_context
return {c:ls for c,ls in by_context.items() if len(ls) >= n}
```

Comment: For `labels` of length 100, your 2 changes improve the speed by about 10%.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation!  I am more of a lurker on SO than a rep collector.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something like these 2 arrays would make a good test case:

```
N = 100
labels=np.arange(N)
contexts=np.random.randint(0,len(labels)/10,len(labels))
```

With these arrays, @Hugh's improvements gain about 10% in speed.

My experience with other problems indicates that a `defaultdict` is a pretty good way of collecting values like this.  The only thing that might be faster is to convert this into some sort of `numpy` indexing problem.